# Initialize std::vector from std::list using iterators

Tags: stl, stdvector, stdlist

I'm trying to initialize a std::vector from a std::list efficiently, but I'm not having any luck.

For example, it'd like to something like this:

```
void myFunc(std::list<double>::iterator begin, std::list<double>::iterator end)
{
    std::vector <double> data(begin, end);
    // or
    std::vector <double> data;
    data::insert(data.begin(), data.end());
}
```

However, this is not working since the containers seem to only support their own iterator types? Am I missing something? Is what I am trying to accomplish not that easily possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first version

```
std::vector<double> data(begin, end);
```

is correct.

You second version should be

```
std::vector<double> data;
data.insert(data.begin(), begin, end);
```

Comment: In both cases I get this error error C2678: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::list<_Ty>::_Iterator<_Secure_validation>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: OK, turns out this was my fault. I was passing a std::list iterator with an offset (mylist.begin() + 40) into the function, and that was the culprit. It works otherwise, like you said. Thanks for confirming.